# Fetch total hours from timin and timout table someone?

Tags: mysql, logic

i have this two tables which when user logs in i store current stimestamp to in timein table with the fields id int 11 auto inc, user_id and time the similaer way i do for logout now my question is how could i get total login hours by calculating from timein and timeout tables with the fields time which is current time stamp? day and month wise

this is how my schema looks like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `timein` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `team` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `timeout` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `team` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: your schema looks wrong, according to my understanding how you manage  relation between login time  and logout time. What is relation between these 2 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For calculate hour use `timestampdiff` function

```
    select *,concat(timestampdiff(hour, a.time, b.time),' hours') from timeout b,timein a
where a.id=b.id
```

Rather than to show only in hour, query below can show in month, day and hour.

```
select 

if(timestampdiff(month,a.time,b.time)>0,concat(timestampdiff(month,a.time,b.time),' month'),

if(datediff(b.time,a.time)>0, concat(datediff(b.time,a.time),' day'),

concat(timestampdiff(hour,a.time,b.time),' hours')))time from timein a,timeout b

where b.id=a.id;
```